# contar los meses que han pasado por año entre dos fechas

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito saber como puedo contar la cantidad de meses por año que han pasado entre dos fechas, por ejemplo tengo un registro de una fecha de `20-01-2015` y yo lo consulto en la fecha de `20-01-2017`, y necesito que me devuelva entre `20-02-2015` hasta `31-12-2015` = 11 meses, `01-01-2016` hasta el `31-12-2016` = 12 meses y así sucesivamente hasta la fecha final.

Comment: Hola Felipe, bienvendio. Que has intentado hasta ahora? muestranos el codigo que tengas, los fallos si los hubiera o por qué te has quedado atascado. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Que definición de mes quieres usar? Según como cuentes del 31-01 al 01-02 puede haber 1 mes o 0 (o 1/30...). Lo mismo del 01-02 al 01-03. Mes es una medida bastante imprecisa.

Comment: Y esto lo intentas hacer en una consulta SQL? En un SP? En algún lenguaje de programación una vez recuperadas las fechas?

Comment: O sea quieres que, dadas dos fechas (una en la BBDD y otra un parámetro tuyo) el resultado devuelva N filas, cada una de ellas correspondiente a la diferencia entre otras dos fechas que no entiendo de donde salen. ¿Por qué el primer resultado empieza con `20-02-2015` y no el mismo `20-01-2015`? por qué el segundo resultado empieza con `01-01-2016`? ¿El tercer resultado empezaría el `01-01-2017`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que buscas es la instruccion TIMESTAMPDIFF la cual la usas de la siguiente manera para tu caso:

```
DECLARE @fecha1 date = '2016-10-14'
DECLARE @fecha2 date = '2017-3-2'

SELECT @TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @fecha1, @fecha2 )
```

Ampliando la respuesta, necesitas generar una lista de años con la diferencia entre ambas fechas y de ahi generar la lista de diferencias usando la instruccion antes comentada

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d215/10/2

**Nota** no tengo mucha idea de como manejar los años biciestos aqui pero no deben de causar mucho problema

Saludos

Comment: Pero esto devolveria la diferencia total de meses, no por años como creo entender que pide @Felipe

Comment: Si ya amplie la respuesta y deje un ejemplo en sqlFiddle, gracias @JosepMonclús

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, te pasaste!